# unable to query mongodb documents using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb version 3.2.10 with database name "football" and collection name "Footballers".

Here is one example of document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58f2c4dfc9f8596b2e50c0c9"), "Name" : "Messi" }
```

I'm trying to pull the records and display on the web page, but I can't get this code to work.
It returns Error

```
CS0411  The type arguments for method 'IMongoDatabase.GetCollection<TDocument>(string, MongoCollectionSettings)'
```

cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

code:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionstring = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionstring);
            var DB = client.GetDatabase("football");

            var collection = DB.GetCollection("Footballers");
            Response.Write(DB.GetCollection("Footballers"));


        }
```

Comment: is that a typo `DB.GetCollection.("Footballers")` ? The dot after `GetCollection` ?

Comment: @Veeram i made an error in posting my code. I removed the . and the code is what I'm trying to run which results in the error message which I updated in the post.